# QR Code import of vCard does not separate fields. Is it the format?

Tags: android, qr-code, vcf-vcard

This text

```
BEGIN:VCARD
N:Haven;Richard;;;
ADR;DOM;PARCEL;HOME:;;9999 Mission Street ;Daly City;California;94014;U.S.A.
EMAIL;INTERNET:richard@domain.com
EMAIL;INTERNET:richard@domain.org
TEL;CELL:831-555-9315
TEL;CELL:831-555-0740
END:VCARD
```

converted into [this QR Code](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chl=BEGIN%3AVCARD%0AN%3AHaven%3BRichard%3B%3B%3B%0AADR%3BDOM%3BPARCEL%3BHOME%3A%3B%3B9999+Mission+Street+%3BDaly+City%3BCalifornia%3B94014%3BU.S.A.%0AEMAIL%3BINTERNET%3Arichard%40domain.com%0AEMAIL%3BINTERNET%3Arichard%40domain.org%0ATEL%3BCELL%3A831-555-9315%0ATEL%3BCELL%3A831-555-0740%0AEND%3AVCARD) and imported into my Motorola Droid does not separate the first and last name, and it does not separate the address.

Also, the phone and emails are assigned Home and Work and Home and Mobile; I expected at least the phones to go in as both Mobile.

Is it just the way Android parses vCards or can I change the encoding to allow separation and correctly specify the types of emails and phones?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question here concerns Barcode Scanner, rather than Android. Barcode Scanner (I'm a developer) parses all these fields. The issue is that the Android 1.x APIs do not let you specify all of the information you want to here as separate fields. Android 2.x does, to a much greater degree. Barcode Scanner must remain compatible with 1.5 for the moment since a small fraction of its users are still on 1.5 -- small fraction, but of 10 million people, so we can't just dump them.

It's conceivable, though quite painful, to write a version that uses one or the other API while still being 1.5-friendly.

Instead there is already a version that requires Android 2.2 and uses newer APIs. It's not going to be released for some time (see above) but you can give it a shot here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner-debug.apk

Comment: If I might impose on your patience a little: it seems that you are saying that the communication between the barcode scanner and the OS is _not_ a simple Intent registration (on "VCARD:"). It seems that you are saying that Barcode Scanner parses the text, determines the format, and explicitly picks which applications it thinks that format might be sent to (e.g. contacts, email, etc.).

Is this correct?

Comment: The debug apk fails to install. I havea 2.2 on a Motorola Droid 1 and have allowed applications from unknown sources (as well as debugging and mock sources). Where should I look for more information?

Thanks

Comment: You have to uninstall the Market version to install my debug version. They're signed with different certificates.

Comment: It is done with an Intent. The Intent does not support these fine-grained fields even in 2.x. It's possible to write code that writes the contact directly and sets these fields individually. However I like the idea of letting the user's preferred app take over this process before saving the contact.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that [mandatory types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426#section-1) are missing: "The vCard object MUST contain the FN, N and VERSION types."

You could also try a vCard validator to see if there are other problems. [Disclaimer: I wrote one]

Comment: No, I added all the fields according to the spec and it still ignores the URL completely and ignores the types of TEL and EMAIL.